# Transform a column of lists into ARRAY type in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am asking some help with the following problem I am facing right now:

I have a csv with the following format:

```
col1, col2
1,    [1.2 4.2 6.3 3.1]
2,    [5.2 5.4 0.3 6.1]
3,    [3.2 0.1 5.3 6.7]
4,    ...
```

When I upload it to BigQuery, it gives me the following format:

```
Row col1 col2
1   1    [1.2 4.2 6.3 3.1]
2   2    [5.2 5.4 0.3 6.1]
3   3    [3.2 0.1 5.3 6.7]
```

What I am trying to do is convert all lists into ARRAY. The output should look like:

```
Row col1 col2
1   1    1.2
         4.3
         6.3 
         3.1
2   2    5.2
         5.4
         0.3
         6.1
3   3    3.2
         0.1
         5.3
         6.7
and more
```

Is there a way to do this with a column with multiple lists?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the type of `col2` in your table?

Comment: good point! It can be a str o python list

Comment: python list ? we are talking about bigquery table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore the functions [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to pull out the list content enclosed in a square bracket [], combined with [`SPLIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) to separate the extracted string into an array of individual values using space ' ' as the delimiter.

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS col1, '[1.2 4.2 6.3 3.1]' AS col2
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '[5.2 5.4 0.3 6.1]'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '[3.2 0.1 5.3 6.7]'
)

SELECT
  col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT
    col1, SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(col2, r'\[(.*?)\]'), ' ') AS col2
  FROM sample_data
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
with test_data as (
  select 1 col1, '[1.2 4.2 6.3 3.1]' col2 union all
  select 2, '[5.2 5.4 0.3 6.1]' union all
  select 3, '[3.2 0.1 5.3 6.7]' 
)
select col1, col2
from test_data, 
unnest(split(trim(col2, '[]'), ' ')) col2
```

with output

[image]

Comment: but what if you have many rows?

Comment: replace `test_data` with your table name! meaning you load your csv into table as you do now and then you use above example to transform data into format you need

Comment: I believe OP may want this query instead (col1 + array): `select col1, split(trim(col2, '[]'), ' ') as col2 from test_data` BR